# Mouse movement on a JavaScript Canvas that works with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I've have recently figured out how to click on a javascript canvas, but there is a problem when I try to scale the image with CSS, it just doesn't work.
This is what I learned to do for the canvas clicking stuff:

```
window.onload = function(){
    c = document.getElementById("C");
    g = c.getContext("2d");
    c.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseUpdate);
}
function mouseUpdate(event){
    mouseX = event.pageX - c.offsetLeft;
    mouseY = event.pageY - c.offsetTop;
}
```

This code works but the second I add CSS to scale the canvas...

```
#C{
    width:80%;
    height:80%;
}
```

The the mouse is miss aligned again.
The canvas is set to be 1920x1080, and scaled down by 80%. Does anyone know already how to fix this problem, because I haven't found anyone else with the same problem that has issues with CSS...

Comment: @K3N I tried that,
     function mouseUpdate(event){
         var rect = c.getBoundingClientRect();
     mouseX = event.pageX - rect.left;
     mouseY = event.pageY - rect.top;
    }

Comment: Note that you need to use the scaling method (not the 1:1 method, see second example "When Element and Bitmap are of different sizes").

Comment: @K3N ok, ill try that

Comment: @K3N I did it and it works perfectly, thanks for the help :)